# Return value from custom hook doesn't get updated outside its file

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have this custom hook in my `DarkModeToggle.js` file:

```
export const useColorScheme = () => {
  const systemPrefersDark = useMediaQuery({
    query: '(prefers-color-scheme: dark)',
  });

  const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode /*,removeThemeState*/] =
    useLocalstorage('isDarkTheme');

  const value = useMemo(
    () =>
      isDarkMode === undefined ||
      isDarkMode === null ||
      (isDarkMode !== undefined &&
        isDarkMode !== null &&
        typeof isDarkMode !== 'boolean')
        ? systemPrefersDark
        : isDarkMode,
    [isDarkMode, systemPrefersDark]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(value);
    if (value) {
      document.body.setAttribute('darkTheme', true);
    } else {
      document.body.removeAttribute('darkTheme');
    }
  }, [value]);
  return [value, setIsDarkMode];
};
```

Then in the component where I'm making use of this hook, I have the following code:

```
const [value] = useColorScheme();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(value);
  }, [value]);
```

The problem is that in the second file, `value` is only logged to the console once even when it changes whereas in the `useEffect` in the `useColorScheme` hook, it always gets logged whenever it changes.